# Android - Is it possible to use Canvas without losing the background?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-custom-view

i am trying to remove a path on a CustomView but the problem is that the background is removed on eraser. I was trying to parse two views of the same size. but the problem shows when i scale the views. I also tried to use two canvas but to no avail.Is there Any way to draw with canvas and not lose the background. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**MyCustomView:**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Message
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColor
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.toDrawable
import kotlin.math.max


class CustomImageView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) :
    AppCompatImageView(context, attributeSet) {
    private var canvas = Canvas()
    private var paint = Paint()
    private var paintBrush = Paint()
    private var paintEraser = Paint()
    private var currentPaintPath = Paint()
    private var path = Path()
    private val pathList = mutableListOf<Stroke>()
    private val backupPath = mutableListOf<Stroke>()
    private val paintPreview = Paint()
    private val drawColor = getColor(context, R.color.green_persian)
    private var strokeSize = STROKE_SIZE
    private var downX = START_POINT
    private var downY = START_POINT
    private var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    private var canvas2 = Canvas()
    private var toolMode = BRUSH_MODE
    private var pointStart = Point()
    private var tracing = false
    private lateinit var findThread: Thread
    private val mGesture: ScaleGestureDetector
    private val maatrix = Matrix()
    init {
        mGesture = ScaleGestureDetector(context, GestureListener())
    }

    private var scaleListener: ScaleListener? = null

    private fun setUpPaint() {
        paintBrush.color = drawColor
        paintBrush.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paintBrush.strokeWidth = strokeSize
        paintBrush.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        paintBrush.isAntiAlias = true

        paintEraser.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paintEraser.strokeWidth = strokeSize
        paintEraser.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        paintEraser.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
        paint = paintBrush
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, focusX, focusY)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
//        canvas?.drawColor(Color.BLUE)
        canvas2.drawColor(Color.BLUE)
        canvas2.drawLine(0f,0f,500f,100f,paint);
        for (p in pathList) {
            paint = p.paint
            paint.strokeWidth = p.strokeSize
            canvas?.drawPath(p.path, paint)
        }
        paint = currentPaintPath
        canvas?.drawPath(path, paint)
    }

    internal fun setStrokeSize(size: Int) {
        strokeSize = STROKE_SIZE + size
        paint.strokeWidth = strokeSize
        paintBrush.strokeWidth = strokeSize
        paintEraser.strokeWidth = strokeSize
        invalidate()
        zoomCallback?.brushSize(size)
    }

    internal fun setEraserTool() {
        toolMode = ERASER_MODE
        paint = paintEraser
        invalidate()
        zoomCallback?.eraser()
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        mGesture.onTouchEvent(event)
    
        return true
    }

    internal fun clearScreen() {
        path.reset()
        pathList.clear()
        backupPath.clear()
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
//        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        invalidate()
        zoomCallback?.clear()
    }

    private var mScaleFactor = 1f
    private var focusX = 0f
    private var focusY = 0f
    private var isScaling = false

    inner class GestureListener : OnScaleGestureListener {
        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.scaleFactor
            mScaleFactor = max(0.5f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 2.0f))
            scaleListener?.onScaleListener(focusX, focusY, mScaleFactor)
            postInvalidate()
            return true
        }

        override fun onScaleBegin(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            isScaling = true
            focusX = detector.focusX
            focusY = detector.focusY
            return true
        }

        override fun onScaleEnd(scaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector) {
            isScaling = false
        }
    }

    internal fun setScaleListener(listener: ScaleListener) {
        this.scaleListener = listener
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageScaleAble
        android:id="@+id/ivOrigin"
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33.7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/item_tools_brush"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bnvTools"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tbTools"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rectangle" />


    <CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPreview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:foregroundTintMode="screen"
        android:contentDescription="@string/item_tools_brush"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivOrigin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivOrigin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivOrigin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivOrigin" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Canvas doesn't have layers or a memory of what's under the pixels in it. It's like working with MSPaint with no undo feature. Once something is drawn, whatever was on those pixels before is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think the implemented logic quite limits the state-saving features.

If you want to implement an undo, redo, visibility of distinct objects(lines and backgrounds and stuff) and many others, I think the best way is to save the lines and shapes as objects in a list, and then draw them on a canvas, so when you "clear" the canvas, you only delete the objects you want to erase from the canvas, so you still have the background shape for the canvas to draw.